# javaee get informations about resteasy version

Tags: jakarta-ee, java-8, resteasy

i am newbie in java developement, i work now on project under JBoss Developer Studio 8.1 + maven project, i have many questions in my mind and i want to have ideas to clearify,

Here i show some maven informations:

- i have an ear project who include an war+ejb projects

and this is what i have as dependencies in my pom.xml :

1. ear pom.xml:

   ```
       <dependency>
           <groupId>com.web2code</groupId>
           <artifactId>pallas-ejb</artifactId>
           <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
           <type>ejb</type>
       </dependency>

       <dependency>
           <groupId>com.web2code</groupId>
           <artifactId>pallas-web</artifactId>
           <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
           <type>war</type>
       </dependency>


       <dependency>
           <groupId>javax</groupId>
           <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
           <version>${version.javaee}</version>
           <scope>provided</scope>
       </dependency>


   </dependencies>
   ```

   - how can i know the RestEasy Version included in my JBDS 8.1 ?
   - how can i use the annotation @FormDataParam in my project to handle the upload form ?
   - is the resteasy implemented with jdk ok JBDS ?

Please can someone help me ? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You should not really care which version RestEasy it is. It is provided by your application server and you don't really care about that, you write code for JAXRS, RestEasy is just one of the implementations. If you want to know the exact version search for it in modules directory of your Wildfly/EAP server. That being said, if you want to use some specific functionality from RestEasy just include the latest one from Maven central.
2. Check this example: http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/file-upload-example-in-resteasy/
3. RestEasy is implementation of JAXRS and is part of JBoss, not JDK.